# Grails gsp won't render correctly

Tags: grails

This is the main login page of my application:

[image]

Once you're logged in, you see this page:

[image]

Now on this page if you press the 'Choose/Upload' button (circled in blue), you get a template rendered in the middle part of the page and then it looks like this:

[image]

If you wait a while such that your session becomes null, then I want the 'Choose/Upload' button to redirect back to the login page, which it does but things look like this:

[image]

This is the controller function associated with the 'Choose/Upload' button:

```
def chooseupload = {
        if (session.user == null) {
            redirect(action: customerLogin)
        }
        else {
            def batchList = (Batch.findAllWhere(userId: session.user.id.toLong(), [sort: "lastUpdate", order: "desc"]))
            render(template: 'chooseupload', model:  [batchList: batchList, batchCount: batchList.size()])
        }

    }
```

and this is the code of the login action:

```
def customerLogin = {
    } //just renders the view customerLogin.gsp
```

Any advice greatly appreciated. I am happy to provide more relevant code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

you seem to be calling `chooseupload` in an AJAX request. If you call redirect in the controller, the browser gets the fully decorated (with header & footer) page back. In order to be able to differentiate between AJAX/noAJAX calls, I'm using the following code:

```
request.xhr ? render( template:'customerLogin' ) : redirect( action:'customerLogin' )
```

Comment: You are exactly right. I don't know why I didn't even think that I am doing an AJAX call. I am still a bit confused as to exactly which part of my code your code would replace. You say that I must redirect in the controller, that bit I understood. customerLogin.gsp is a full view not a template, that's why I got confused by your code. Can you explain a bit more please? And both of my above methods are in the controller so am I not redirecting in the controller as I should?

Comment: you should replace the line `redirect(action: customerLogin)` with the code I posted. With full view I meant, that the page you render (or redirect to) gets `decorated` by Grails' `sitemesh` filter. see the grails ref-doc, it's very well explained there

Comment: With your solution, I now get this when I click on the 'Choose/Upload' button when the session is null: `| Error 2014-08-31 17:28:34,101 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ControllerExecutionException occurred when processing request: [POST] /FatcaOne_0/customer/chooseupload
Unable to load template for uri [/customer/_customerLogin.gsp]. Template not found.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Unable to load template for uri [/customer/_customerLogin.gsp]. Template not found.
    Line | Method
->>   71 | doCall  in com.twc.fatcaone.CustomerController$_closure5$$EOoXEy12
`

Comment: use `render( view:'customerLogin' )`

Comment: This is the line of code I am using now `request.xhr ? render( template:'customerLogin' ) : render( view:'customerLogin' )` and I left it over night so the session could get nulled and when I hit choose/upload button this morning this is what I got: `| Error 2014-09-01 13:45:14,850 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ControllerExecutionException occurred when processing request: [POST] /FatcaOne_0/customer/chooseupload
Unable to load template for uri [/customer/_customerLogin.gsp]. Template not found.. Stacktrace follows:
`

Comment: instead of `template` you should use `view` in your `render` call

Comment: Ok now it does redirect but exactly as I describe in the original question. It looks funny just like I put in the photo. Its not a whole new page still ajax style. Just for experimentation this is how I tried it. `request.xhr ? render( view:'customerLogin' ) : render( view:'customerLogin' )`

Comment: extract the "body" part of customerLogin.gsp into `_customerLogin.gsp` template (and `render` it inside the customerLogin.gsp of course). Thus you can have `request.xhr ? render( template:'customerLogin' ) : render( view:'customerLogin' )`